# How to get stream data from (web) MediaRecorder based on size instead of time?

Tags: javascript, typescript, navigator, web-mediarecorder

I'm currently using `MediaRecorder` to get chunks of a video stream from the user's webcam / mic like so:

```
navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true})
    .then((stream) => {
      var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
      mediaRecorder.start(5000);

      mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (blobEvent) => {
        console.log('got 5 seconds of stream', blobEvent);
      }
    })
```

this emits a chunk of the stream of every 5 seconds of video, however, I want chunks at a particular size, rather than length.  There doesn't seem to be a clear way to do this, since I can't check the size of the current chunk without starting a new one, and I can't combine them after the fact.  This is the work around I've come up with, using 2 media recorders:

```
  const MIN_BLOB_SIZE = 5000000;
  var partSize = 0;
  navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true})
    .then((stream) => {
      var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
      var mediaRecorder2 = new MediaRecorder(stream)
      mediaRecorder.start();
      mediaRecorder2.start(5000)

      mediaRecorder2.ondataavailable = (blobEvent) => {
          console.log('got 5 seconds of data', blobEvent)
          const blob = blobEvent.data
          partSize += blob.size;
          if (partSize >= MIN_BLOB_SIZE) {
              partSize = 0;
              mediaRecorder.requestData();
          }
      }

      mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (blobEvent) => {
        console.log('got a chunk at least 5mb', blobEvent);
      };
    });
```

but this feels hacky, gives imprecise chunks, requires me to make sure these two recorders are perfectly synced, complicates error handling / edge cases, and I'm concerned about performance implications of using 2 media recorders.  Would accept an answer that gets this done with one media recorder, or, if that’s just not possible, if someone can convince me that 2 media recorders is fine performance wise, I would also accept that and handle the complications it creates.

Comment: Did you find a good solution for this? Facing something similar.

Comment: @user13628417 the answer i got below worked well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Combining Chunks

You *can* combine chunks after the fact with [`new Blob(blobArray)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob). If you absolutely need to process blobs of a certain size, you can use [`Blob.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/slice). It could look something like this:

```
const MIN_BLOB_SIZE = 5000000;
var partSize = 0, parts = [];
navigator.mediaDevices
  .getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true})
  .then((stream) => {
    var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    mediaRecorder.start(5000);
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (blobEvent) => {
        console.log('got 5 seconds of data', blobEvent);
        const blob = blobEvent.data;
        partSize += blob.size;
        parts.push(blob);
        if (partSize >= MIN_BLOB_SIZE) {
            let bigBlob = new Blob(parts, { type: blob.type });
            // if the blob size doesn't need to be precise:
            partSize = 0;
            parts = [];
            // do something with bigBlob

            // or if the blob size needs to be precise:
            // let sizedBlob = bigBlob.slice(0, MIN_BLOB_SIZE, blob.type);
            // parts = [ bigBlob.slice(MIN_BLOB_SIZE, bigBlob.size, blob.type) ];
            // partSize = parts[0].size;
            // do something with sizedBlob

        }
    };
    mediaRecorder.onstop = (blobEvent) => {
        console.log('Recording Stopped');
        const blob = blobEvent.data;
        partSize += blob.size;
        parts.push(blob);
        let bigBlob = new Blob(parts, { type: blob.type });
        // do something with bigBlob, which may be smaller than MIN_BLOB_SIZE
    };
});
```

### Tuning Blob Size with Bitrate

You also might be interested in the `bitsPerSecond` (and also the `audioBitsPerSecond` and `videoBitsPerSecond`) option in the [MediaRecorder API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/MediaRecorder), which might give you more predictable blob sizes for a given recorded amount of time. This may affect video and audio quality though.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'll give this a test and see if it does what I need it to do. the precision of the blobs isn't very important. more a nice to have.